# Providing library version from module which includes the lib

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a webapp and currently developing a payment API as an external module or jar.

Webapp is based on `Spring Boot` so it is auto configuring a lot of stuff underhood including logging.

Now, payment library is also using logging, but I had to include:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And use it like this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Client.class);
```

In short I want to avoid dependency hell of logging libraries from webapp vs payment.

Is it possible somehow to make payment module use logging libraries from webapp instead of providing them in the second module? If not, what would be a good practice in such situation?